# Able to read external RSS feeds, but Local Feeds are not found

Tags: rss, dotnetnuke, asp.net-4.5

I have both DNN 6.x and 7.x sites & asp.net 4.5. I have tested a few RSS reader modules.

If I include an RSS feed from another site they work fine, but when I attempt to read an RSS feed from another page on the same site it fails.

I have tested the Local RSS feed and it is valid.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use fiddler for this kind of situations. You can install and start fiddler and navigate to the page where the module is installed and feeds are not loading.

You will see the feed url  request and status code that will help you debugging/troubleshooting the problem.